# Double-free error when using std::ptr::read in Rust

Tags: pointers, memory, rust, unsafe, double-free

i am trying to read a value from pointer but i always get a `double-free` error. Do you guys know a way to fix it? I am using `mem::forget` to block the free operation but i still get the same result.

```rust
use std::ptr;
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    let test = String::from("hello!");
    println!("{}", get_value_from_ptr(&test));
    println!("{}", get_value_from_ptr(&test));
}

fn get_value_from_ptr<T>(val: &T) -> T {
    let value = unsafe { ptr::read(val) };
    mem::forget(&value);
    value
}
```

Error:

```bash
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.26s
     Running `target/debug/playground`
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
timeout: the monitored command dumped core
/playground/tools/entrypoint.sh: line 11:     8 Aborted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mem::forget()` must take an *owned* value. If you provide it with a reference, it'll forget the reference - which is meaningless since references do not have a `Drop` glue anyway. You'll have to `mem::forget(value)` and not `mem::forget(&value)`, but then you move out of `value` and you cannot return it.

What you're trying to do is fundamentally impossible. You cannot duplicate a value soundly if it does not implement `Copy`. Even just `ptr::read()`ing it may invalidate the original value, even if you immediately `forget()` it ([this is not decided yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/307)). Using it after is a non-starter.

Comment: But i need to shallow-copy the value without cloning it. Does Rust have an "unsafe" way to do that?

Comment: @aiocat Sorry to disappoint you, but this is fundamentally impossible: a type that can be bitwise duplicated is `Copy`. If a type does not implement that trait, then by definition it cannot be duplicated, at least without extra code (`Clone`). You may need to ask a new question with a more concrete use-case; maybe you're looking for `Rc`?

Comment: No it is possible, but doing so is wildly unsafe. I would also recommend using `Rc` instead. You can improve the code in the question by using `ManuallyDrop<T>` and making `get_value_from_ptr` unsafe. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b84fb9892e10c17a06d4e9cd5739145e

Comment: @Locke No, this is not possible, this is undefined behavior. You cannot duplicate a `String` bitwisely. `ManuallyDrop` is many times better than `mem::forget()` indeed, I didn't suggest it because the intent is impossible to achieve in this case anyway.

Comment: is [this](https://gist.github.com/rust-play/60d8df6508ac5a7f72e3d834fb3a8004) a valid way to use `Rc`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman We have already established that the usage is undefined behavior, but this is by no means impossible. The question fundamentally boils down to perfectly copying and returning one piece of memory without modifying the original. With a little unsafe code this is easy for any sized type. Attempting to then use that copy for literally anything afterwards is the issue. I think that this is important since the type being copied might not be a string. For all we know, `String` may just be a placeholder for some complex `extern "C"` type.

Comment: @Locke thank you! it worked, but whats is the "downside" of using `ManuallyDrop<T>` instead of `Rc<T>`? like trying to read a null pointer?

Comment: @aiocat Basically everything Chayim said. My answer is more just for completeness. Just use an `Rc`.

Comment: @aiocat The "only" downside is that you're doing thing that are completely unsound and may become UB tomorrow or yesterday. Don't do that.

Comment: [Here's a simple example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b875242e3adcf3fc0cf61708e4a75f02) where usage of `ManuallyDrop` in your function can be turned into complete undefined behavior by all means that is even reported by Miri (and worse, happens to work).

Comment: I am using `Rc<T>` now. thanks for helping @ChayimFriedman & @Locke!